# Cannot build Docker-Compose using React, Node, and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build an application with React.js for a project where I need to use docker-compose. I'm using node for the backend and mongoDB for database.

I'm able to start docker-compose outside of a react where I know the path works. I suspect that my issue has to do with the path that I am using. Below you will see the path hierarchy.

[image]

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  server:
    build:
      context: ./my-app/src/server
      dockerfile: ./my-app/src/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
      - './app/node_modules'
    command: "npx nodemon src/server.js"

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm init -y

RUN npm install express body-parser mongo nodemon
```

I have a basic server.js where I didn't connect mongoDB yet, but I believe it shouldn't matter.

```
'use strict';


// load package
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const PORT = 8000;
const HOST = "0.0.0.0";

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/my-app/public/index.html"));
});
app.listen(PORT,HOST);
console.log("up and running");
```

For context, this is how I ran my docker-compose in this file hierarchy:
[image]

The only difference in this docker-compose.yml is having `context: ./server`, `docker file: ./Dockerfile` and

```
volumes:
      - "./server:/app/src"
    command: "npx nodemon src/server.js"
```

When running `docker-compose build` this is the error that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[1247] Failed to execute script docker-compose
(base) raff@Raphaels-Air Project %
```

Comment: You can't have your `build.dockerfile` (`./my-app/src/Dockerfile`) be outside the `build.context` directory (`./my-app/src/server`). See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context... _"Either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url to a git repository"_

Comment: I tried changing that now to 
```
 context: ./my-app/src/server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```  
which still gives me the same error

Comment: I don't think you understand. The context should be a directory containing a Dockerfile. If you set it to `./my-app/src/server` then there should be a `./my-app/src/server/Dockerfile` present. You do not need to set the `dockerfile`  property

Comment: I have set up other docker-composes in that way, and it worked. However, even if I don't set the docker file property I still get an error message